# How to handle ImportError: cannot import name '_ellipsoid' Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, image-preprocessing

I am getting an error which says 
ImportError: cannot import name '_ellipsoid' 
while importing 
"from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator ".
Please help me to rectify this issue.
I am using 
keras version: 2.1.5
python version: 3

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would be helpful, if you could provide a little bit more information about the circumstances of the error, ideally the relevant part of your code. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to learn more about what information to include in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (ImportError: cannot import name '_ellipsoid') when importing

```
from keras.models import Sequential
```

I solved it by upgrading the version of scipy, since that is the python module that is being imported and should have _ellipsoid. Run the following command

```
pip install --upgrade scipy
Successfully installed scipy-1.0.1
```

With this version of scipy and keras version 2.1.6 I have no problem now